# What is non-degenerate Four Wave Mixing?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics

I am going through some of the papers and the term "non-degenerate Four-Wave Mixing" came up. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Specific references to, or links to, the papers where you found this term would help us to clarify its meaning for you.

Comment: I can only echo Rob's comment. If you have any future question,  can I suggest you look through Wikipedia (or search the internet) first, read the article and **then** ask about points you may not follow. No offence meant to you, but a one line, no reference, no effort shown question is not the best way to get results.

Comment: @rob Four-Wave Mixing is a perfectly standard term in nonlinear optics. I would normally just recommend that the OP read up on the Wikipedia page on it, but to be frank it's not particularly useful, and neither is the first page of google results.

Comment: The Wikipedia article is exceptionally poor.  It focuses entirely on the degradation of communication signals.   However, four wave mixing has other applications, particularly in spectroscopy and high-speed chemical dynamics studies.   Resonance allows for specificity in the determination of mechanisms.  Entirely missing from Wikipedia is a discussion of the essential feature of phase matching.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar in some ways to the beats phenomenon in sound waves.

Four mixing can develop as a byproduct from a third order optical nonlinearity.  Assume at least two components of non identical frequencies travel together in say a fibre optic cable, that is a non linear medium. Assign the input frequencies the labels  $f_1$ and $f_2$ and presume that $f_2 > f_1$.

What will then result is a refractive index modulation, the properties and nature of which depend on the frequency difference noted above. Following from this , we will end up with two more frequency components, so leaving us, starting from a two component system, with 4 components in total.

[image]

Image Source: [Wikipedia page on Four-Wave Mixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-wave_mixing)

> Energy level diagram for a non-degenerate four-wave mixing process. The top energy level could be a real atomic or molecular level (resonant four-wave mixing) or a virtual level, far detuned off-resonance. This diagram describes the four-wave mixing interaction between frequencies $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_3$ and $f_4$.

In addition to these new frequency components, if there is already a wave at either of  the $f_3$ or $f_4$  frequencies, it can undergo  parametric amplification .

This is called non-degenerate four-wave mixing, reflecting the fact that all 4 components are at different frequencies.

A better, fuller  explanation can be found at the [Wikipedia page on Four-Wave Mixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-wave_mixing)

Comment: This is mostly on the dot, except for the conditions on $f_3$ and $f_4$. On the general case there is no such condition: any frequency pair can be emitted, as long as it is correctly [phase matched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics#Phase_matching).